# Find the number of black and white clips

Tags: probability

> One bag contains 15 clips which are black and white. A student takes a clip out of the bag 100 times with replacement, and records the results on a blackboard. The student found that the black clip came out 40 times. Find the number of black and white clips.

It just the solution in the textbook. So I don’t think like that. If you have any ideas to share to me please let me to know. Especially, if you have any answer please let me to see.

---

Let $x$ be the number of black clips. Then we have the probability $$P=\frac{x}{15}$$
Furthermore $$P’=\frac{40}{100}$$
So we get $P=P’$
$\longrightarrow$ $x=6$

Comment: Please don't shout in large bold font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not exactly well-posed. The solution is just saying that our best guess of the actual probability is best estimated through our observed empirical probability. Thus 'our best guess' as to the number of black clips is 6. We do not definitively know that the correct number is 6.

If there are $x$ black clips (of the 15 total) then the probability of drawing a black clip any one time is $\frac{x}{15}$ (this is your $P$ above). $P'$ is our empirical estimate of $P$ from the 'experiment' that we have run (drawn 100 clips with replacement).

Comment: So this probability, we can’t do like the above answer from textbook.  So how can we denote $P’$